# Customizing list of file formats available when loading QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-customization

QGIS is able to load an impressive list of file formats, both vector and raster.  For example, here's a screenshot of just some of the raster formats available when using the *Data Source Manager* popup window at 3.10.5:

[image]

However, this eye-watering list is too extensive for my needs. I would like to remove those formats that I will never use, so that such popups contain only those formats that are of interest to me (for example, those highlighted in red).

I looked through *Settings > Interface Customization*, but did not see anything related.

How do I customize the list of file formats available when loading?

Comment: I think they are kind of embed during compilation time, so, unless you want to get your hands in there I guess you cannot.

Comment: GDAL should support a `GDAL_SKIP` environment variable - I can reduce the number of drivers shown by `gdalinfo --formats` but QGIS is unaffected. Hmmm...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Settings, Options, GDAL and switch off the drivers you don't want to use.

[image]

That will reduce the Raster options, I don't currently see a way to do similar for vector data.

Note this will stop qgis showing any rasters in the disabled formats, not just remove them from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to remove file formats from the importing or exporting list in QGIS. The program is designed to open as many file formats as possible since it was created to be used opensource and for various fields of work. However, by default the program will import layers and data with the "All files" option enabled. Therefore you will never need to open that list unless you want to know if you can import a different file format than you are used to.